# Conflicto con ngRoute y JQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ngroute

Colegas,
tengo el siguiente escenario, estoy construyendo una página web de tipo `SPA` (*Single Page Application*), por lo que necesito trabajar con `$routeProvider` para enlazar las rutas a cada vista. Hasta ahí todo bien, las rutas dinámicas me funcionan correctamente; el problema aparece que a pesar de realizar lo que necesito, la **consola de Chrome** me detecta un error de tipo

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/home.

Investigando probé distintas formas para evitar esto (*quitando el slash, quitan el hashtag, etc*) sin resultado alguno. 
Asímismo este error me repercute en que estoy cargando inicialmente un slider con `owl-carousel`, pero al cambiar de página y volver al slider inicial no me muestra las imágenes =/

Les adjunto el código HTML

```
<nav id="nav-menu-container">
   <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="menu-active"><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/places">About Us</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

y el JS

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider
      .when('/', { templateUrl: 'Pages/paraphrasing.html', controller: 'indexController' })
      .when('/home', { templateUrl: 'Pages/paraphrasing.html', controller: 'indexController' })
      .when('/places', { templateUrl: 'Pages/Norte/iregion.html', controller: 'northZoneController' })
}]);
```

Alguna sugerencia que puedan indicarme para corregir esto? Se agradecería

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a cambiar los enlaces para usar `ui-sref=`
Algo asi:

```
<nav id="nav-menu-container">
   <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="menu-active"><a href="#" ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ui-sref="places">About Us</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza colega, finalmente el problema venía de la versión que estaba utilizando de jQuery... actualice a la 3.3.1 y no tuve problema; además aplique tu solución y me funciono perfecto... Agradecido!